# Bad request while sending multpart image through retrofit 2.1.0

Tags: android

```
private void saveImageToServer(final String savedpath) {
        showLoader();
        NetworkUtil.checkInternetConnection(DetailActiveSRActivity.this, new NetworkUtil.NetworkStatusListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNetworkAvailable() {
                File file = new File(savedpath);
                // RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), savedpath);
                RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
                Log.e(TAG, "onNetworkAvailable: requestFIle " + savedpath+"\n"+" file "+file);
               MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestFile);
                Log.e(TAG, "onNetworkAvailable: body " + body);
                RequestBody reqUserId = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), userId);
                //RequestBody reqImageType =RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "1");
                Call<SaveImageResponseModel> responseCall = mService.saveImages(body, reqUserId);
                responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<SaveImageResponseModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<SaveImageResponseModel> call, retrofit2.Response<SaveImageResponseModel> response) {
                        hideLoader();
                        if (response != null) {
                            SaveImageResponseModel apiResponse = response.body();
                            if (apiResponse != null && apiResponse.getStatus()) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "onRequestSuccess: " + apiResponse);

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(DetailActiveSRActivity.this, getString(R.string.noDataError), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(DetailActiveSRActivity.this, getString(R.string.noDataError), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<SaveImageResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
                        hideLoader();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onNetworkNotAvailable() {
                Toast.makeText(DetailActiveSRActivity.this, getString(R.string.noNetworkMessage), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                hideLoader();
            }
        });
    }



 @Headers({
            "authkey: ABCD@123"
    })
    @Multipart
    @POST(UrlUtils.POST_IMAGES)
    Call<SaveImageResponseModel> saveImages(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("userId") RequestBody userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, no description, please add a little bit more.

Second:

- show what is the content of `mService.saveImages(body, reqUserId);`
- is the HTTP call of POST type?
- is the endpoint really working? You should for example try to make call through Postman and you'll see, if it is going through